# Copy word tables into a new word document

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I have a word document that contains about 1000 tables, each with their captions. I want group these tables into 100 groups (i.e. 10 tables in each group) and then save each group in a new word document ("newdoc.docx" which I have saved on my desktop). Is there any VBA code or macro in word that can help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

here is a snippet to get you started

```
Sub copyTable()

    ' one table is already in document

    Dim srcDoc As Document
    Set srcDoc = ActiveDocument

    Dim destDoc As Document
    Set destDoc = ActiveDocument    ' same doc in this example

    Dim tabl As Table
    Set tabl = srcDoc.Tables(1)


    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = destDoc.Range            ' whole doc
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd         ' collapse range into an insert point at end of doc

    tabl.Range.Copy                    ' source table
                                       ' ( could not figure out how to copy directly without copy/paste )
    rng.Paste                          ' paste at insert point

End Sub
```